# Dynamically create a mat-step outside of mat-horizontal-stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I am trying to create a dynamic stepper form in angular material. I have defined my main components as such

my-stepper.component.ts

```js
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

in another file I defined my steps so I can generate these with an *ngFor

my-stepper-step.component.ts

```js
<mat-step>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-step>
```

Now I want to generate the stepper by creating another component and loading this

```js
<my-stepper>
  <my-stepper-step *ngFor="let num of nums">
    {{ nums }}
  </my-stepper-step>
</my-stepper>
```

This however gives the error **NullInjectorError: No provider for MatStepper!**. I believe this has to do with mat-step needing to be enclosed in a mat-horizontal-stepper, and this actually is done via ng-content but not directly. Is there a way to load mat-steps outside of the stepper?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/stepper/stepper.ts#L158

`mat-stepper` must wrap `mat-step` directly:

```
<mat-stepper orientation="vertical" [linear]="true" #stepper>
  <mat-step *ngFor="let num of nums">
    {{ num }}
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```